# JQuery Cycle Plugin not displaying an image

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I'm running into an issue getting a fourth image to display using the JQuery Cycle Plugin. The first three images cycle fine, but the fourth image will not display.

The path name for the image works when accessed here: http://www.camavision.com/wp/images/ad-get-your-business-noticed.png

Here is my code and displaying the error when it comes to not displaying the fourth banner:

```
        <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="-image-" width="320" height="85">
    <img src="-image-" width="320" height="85">
    <img src="-image-" width="320" height="85">
    <img src="-imagead-.png" width="320" height="85">
</div>
```

Full code can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/eymqh3yf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adblock is blocking it. When I disable the plugin it loads fine in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Hence the theme of the image, great catch! Thanks!